# Django admin terrible performance get_form queryset filter when adding order_by

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm encountering some terrible performance issues when trying to filter a forms queryset.

I'm trying to filter a Model where a relationship already exists.

The code is successful.

But my queryset is not ordered.

The moment I change to `form.base_fields['sharepoint_mandate'].queryset = Sharepoint_Mandate.objects.filter(mandate_mapping_2__isnull=True).order_by('product_name')` the query now takes 25 seconds

Please help

**models.py**

```
class Mandate_Mapping_2(Trackable):
    mandate_mapping_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  
    sharepoint_mandate = models.ForeignKey(Sharepoint_Mandate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    sharepoint_product = models.ForeignKey(Sharepoint_Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Mandate_Mapping_2)
class ChampMandateMapping2Admin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_display =  ['sharepoint_mandate', 'sharepoint_product', 'approved']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):        
        form = super(ChampMandateMapping2Admin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

        if 'change' in kwargs:
            if not kwargs['change']:
                form.base_fields['sharepoint_mandate'].queryset = Sharepoint_Mandate.objects.filter(mandate_mapping_2__isnull=True)
        return form

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).select_related(
            'sharepoint_product', 
            'sharepoint_mandate',
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

When checking the existence of a Mandate_Mapping_2 for a Sharepoint_Mandate you are making an extra query for nothing. You can use the column name attribute.

```
Sharepoint_Mandate.objects.filter(mandate_mapping_2_id=None).order_by('product_name')
```

You can look at **"Use foreign key values directly"** part in [Django database access optimization docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i have placed that into my get_form 
 and again `Sharepoint_Mandate.objects.filter(mandate_mapping_2=None)` fast `Sharepoint_Mandate.objects.filter(mandate_mapping_2=None).order_by('product_name')` slow