# How do i display a filtered selection list in django form

Tags: django, django-admin

My problem is this: I have a list of people that can be selected as people that can attend a meeting. Accounts that are inactive should not be displayed in that list. I want to filter those accounts out of the list of possible users to select

This is what the code looks like now:

```
class StudioMeetingNoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('this_is_test',)
    fieldsets = [
        ('Tijden', {'fields': ['meeting_start_time', 'meeting_end_time']}),
        ('Wie is de voorzitter/notulist', {'fields': [('chairman', 'secretary')]}),
        ('Opkomst', {'fields': [('attending_persons', 'absent_persons')]}),
    ]
    inlines = [OpeningAndParticularitiesInline, ActionListPointInline, RemarksPriorMeetingInline, IssuesToAddressInline, OurNextMoveInline, QuestionRoundInline]
    list_filter = ['meeting_start_time']
    search_fields = ['meeting_start_time']
    list_display = ('meeting_start_time', 'chairman', 'secretary')
```

The field `attending_persons` should be filtered, so no inactive user accounts should be shown.
I tried replacing 'attending_persons'  with a method like they show in the link below, but that causes an error.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'title', 'view_birth_date')

    def view_birth_date(self, obj):
        return obj.birth_date

    view_birth_date.empty_value_display = '???'
```

You can't do this with a `fieldset`

So my question is: How do i display a filtered list to choose from?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `get_form`method:

```
class StudioMeetingNoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # same as above ...

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(StudioMeetingNoteAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['attending_persons'].queryset = User.objects.filter(active=True)
        return form
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields):

> The fields option accepts the same types of values as list_display, except that ***callables aren’t accepted***. Names of model and model admin methods will only be used if they’re listed in readonly_fields.

This is for `ModelAdmin.fields`, but the same rule will apply for `ModelAdmin.fieldsets`

Comment: hello Pedram, when i try your solution with `.fieldsets` it says ` AttributeError: type object 'StudioMeetingNoteForm' has no attribute 'fieldsets'
`

Comment: @FAM_Maurice You should use `.fields` **not** `fieldsets` (form has fields).

Comment: ok i changed it to fields, but now i get the error `tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I have discovered that it should not be `fields`, instead it should be `base_fields`. I've used the quoted code from this question as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54777663/django-admin-terrible-performance-get-form-queryset-filter-when-adding-order-by and now it works. No more errors, so i think you should adjust your answer @Pedram Parsian

Comment: heres another explanatory link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140862/fields-and-base-fields-django I forgot to mention that i got an 'AttributeError: type object 'StudioMeetingNoteForm' has no attribute 'fields''  error. According to the explanation this happens when you try to use fields before calling `super()`

Comment: I call `super()` first and then try to access `fields` (or `base_fields`); So there shouldn't be an issue there.